# Qgis2threejs Can't see option button

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs

I just installed Qgis2threejs 2.2 for QGIS 3.2.3 and it works fine but I can't see the options of the plugin anywhere. There is supposed to be a blue one but nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just found a workaround by right click on the layer in the 3d window then properties